# Why is my Object's Origin corrupting its Surface Deform modifier results?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, error, origin

I'm encountering a super perplexing issue where the `Surface Deform` modifier I've applied to a low-res mesh *mostly* works, but results in a few arbitrary vertices ignoring the `Surface Deform` target, and instead decide to point away from the position of the origin.  It took me about an hour of experimentation to even realize what was going on.  I have a video demonstrating my issue below.

[Video demonstrating my problem](https://streamable.com/v4dl76)

Does this make any sense to anyone?  What am I doing wrong to cause my origin to affect (or appear to affect) my `Surface Deform` results, and what should I check to get it to behave as intended?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** File attached!
[image]

Comment: hello, could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Great idea! Here's the link (also edited the OP) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0G8aZzSM/

Comment: yes that's weird, I don't know why you want to use surface deform with a high-poly as target object but this doesn't answer  ;)

Comment: Trying to retopologize clothing using the method seen in [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuaRHETMpto&t=575s).  I removed a lot of stuff from the file for the purpose of sharing my problem.

Comment: setting the origin to geometry helps but doesn't completely fix the problem, I hope someone will give the answer

Comment: Have you read the warning part here? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html (@moonboots)

Comment: @lemon, the target mesh seems ok, are you able to find what's the problem?

Comment: Yep, none of the issues in the warning stick out to me as likely culprits - and certainly don't explain why the couple of verts that are exploding are deciding to do so.

Comment: Was thinking about concavities... but if we take the circular part separated, the issue still occurs. So, this is not that.

Comment: No explaination. Though, as the issue occurs on few vertices, a workaround it to add an edge crossing the faces of the highpoly for faces that are next to these few vertices.

Comment: That would be a nice workaround, what's not included in my file is the Subdivision modifier that I want to add before the Surface Deform, and makes the problem much worse. :(

Comment: Bug submitted! https://developer.blender.org/T81988